# scala exception in for-comprehension with type annotation

Tags: scala, for-comprehension, scala-2.11

I am trying to understand what seems like strange behavior when dealing with nulls and type annotations inside a for-comprehension.

As an example:

```
def f(): String = null

for {
  a <- Option("hello")
  b = f()
} yield (a, b)
```

results in the expected:

```
//> res0: Option[(String, String)] = Some((hello,null))
```

however, if I add a type annotation to the type of `b`

```
def f(): String = null

for {
  a <- Option("hello")
  b: String = f()
} yield (a, b)
```

then I get a runtime exception:

```
//> scala.MatchError: (hello,null) (of class scala.Tuple2)
```

Why does this happen? Isn't `b` implicitly of type `String` in the first example anyway? What does the explicit type annotation in the second example change?

(Note, examples were run in Scala 2.11.4)

Comment: The second example compiles to a match, as you can see using `reify` in the repl: `import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._; reify {for {... } }`. I can't tell you why though. AIUI `null` doesn't match because matching works on the runtime type (or value), even though `b` has a compile-time type of `String`; this is in some sense a hole in the type system, and scala code should generally avoid using nulls.

Comment: I am no fan of nulls, believe me! In the actual code where I stumbled upon this I was using `Try`s to integrate with some legacy java code. However, null seems incidental to me here: the aspect I find bizarre (scary?) is that adding more type specificity results in an (unintuitive) runtime exception.

Comment: It's a weirdness of the language that putting types in a `for`/`yield` results in a pattern match; it's not a problem that would occur with "ordinary" types on expressions. All I can say is it's unfortunate, but probably can't be changed at this stage; I tend to avoid ever giving a type on the left hand side of a for/yield for this reason :/

Comment: @lmm I think I'll stop typing the LHS too! Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`null` is not an instance of anything:

```
scala> (null: String) match { case _: String => }
scala.MatchError: null
  ... 33 elided

scala> val s: String = null
s: String = null

scala> s.isInstanceOf[String]
res1: Boolean = false
```

http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#type-patterns

Type pattern specifies non-null.

One trick for showing the translation is to comment show:

```
scala> for {
     |   a <- Option("hello")
     |   b: String = f()
     | } yield (a, b) // show
object $read extends scala.AnyRef {
  def <init>() = {
    super.<init>;
    ()
  };
  object $iw extends scala.AnyRef {
    def <init>() = {
      super.<init>;
      ()
    };
    import $line4.$read.$iw.$iw.f;
    object $iw extends scala.AnyRef {
      def <init>() = {
        super.<init>;
        ()
      };
      val res1 = Option("hello").map(((a) => {
        val b: String = f;
        scala.Tuple2(a, b)
      })).map(((x$1) => x$1: @scala.unchecked match {
        case scala.Tuple2((a @ _), (b @ (_: String))) => scala.Tuple2(a, b)
      }))
    }
  }
}
scala.MatchError: (hello,null) (of class scala.Tuple2)
  at $anonfun$2.apply(<console>:10)
  at $anonfun$2.apply(<console>:10)
  at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
  ... 39 elided
```

Comment: That shows what is going wrong, but it's arguably a bug because there's no reason to pattern match on that last map since it _by construction_ already has the correct type (at `val b: String = f`).  (It's also arguably a bug that the identity function isn't optimized out, but we can imagine a more complex case.)

Comment: @RexKerr yes, arguably. It's a stronger arg if it used the old `val b: String = f()` syntax, maybe modulo SI-900 where type pat on generator means filter. But you wouldn't optimize the ordinary match. Maybe we should start writing `val i = 42 : Int`. Then `val s : String = null : String` could fail as though wrapped in `Tuple1`.

Comment: Does the language spec dictate that the de-sugaring of the type annotation in the comprehension be implemented as a pattern match?

Comment: @bkent314 Yes. Unlike a regular val definition, the LHS is a pattern1. http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#for-comprehensions-and-for-loops Compare pattern2 in http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#value-declarations-and-definitions